# Can we configure application.properties through a db

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring-boot, application.properties

I have different products and every products has some attributes which i am specifying in application.properties so everytime i need to add field in application.properties and relaunch the server. I want it to be more dynamic and to directly fetch it from the database in run time. Any solution or suggestion will be helpful for me?

i tried to directly configure application.properties using queries in database and perform dynamically. But not able to proceed?

Comment: Application.properties file gets intialized during application startup i.e. when applicationContext or Spring IOC container is initialized. You can have multiple such files but cannot dynamically populate it , since by the time you have read from DB , that file is already initialized and in-use. I suggest to re-visit Spring and Spring boot concepts

Comment: actually for every products some fields for that country level i need to fill in application.properties so that only i need to configure from db

Answer (score 0):

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_dynamic_config")
public class DynamicConfig {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String key;
    private String value;

}

public interface DynamicConfigDao extends JpaRepository<DynamicConfig,Integer> {
    DynamicConfig findByKey(String key);
}

public class DynamicConfigPropertySource extends EnumerablePropertySource<DynamicConfigDao> {

    public DynamicConfigPropertySource(String name, DynamicConfigDao source) {
        super(name, source);
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getPropertyNames() {
        return getSource().findAll().stream().map(DynamicConfig::getKey).toArray(String[]::new);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(String name) {
        return getSource().findByKey(name).getValue();
    }

}


@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Component
    static class ConfigDynamicConfigPropertySource implements SmartInitializingSingleton {
        @Autowired
        private ConfigurableEnvironment environment;
        @Autowired
        private DynamicConfigDao dynamicConfigDao;

        @Override
        public void afterSingletonsInstantiated() {
            environment.getPropertySources().addLast(new DynamicConfigPropertySource("db_source",dynamicConfigDao));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is that sufficient to create dynamic query and fetch resuts from database?

Comment: like i have country.properties file for different country related information and i need that to directly fetch from database only. Any help from ur side is appreciated!!